# encryption decryption in java and javascript

Tags: java, javascript, encryption

I am calling a restful web service written in java from java script page and from restful  web  service i am returning J SON data. how can i encrypt the j son data in java so that no one can see the data using firebug and again i need to decrypt the data in java script page.
Somewhere i read about b son but i couldn't get much info about this.
Is there any way to do this.
Thanks in advance.
i am making ajax call from java script like this...

```
$.post(url,{cache: false, "_": $.now() },function(){
            //  code
        }, "json");

and from server i am returning json data like this
objectmapper.writeValueAsString("String data");
```

Comment: If you're sending something to the client and *anything* (like your JavaScript code) can decode it, then the user can see it.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of which encryption you use between the client and the server, there must be a point for the client where the data can be read. That is in the browser, which is exposed to javascript, and therefore to Firebug.

Bson is bynary Json (http://bsonspec.org/), and, unless javascript reads and writes the stream by itself (without parsing it into a clear text object), you would fall into the same problem.